# Single for loop for multiple Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I was wondering, if it is possible to run 1 **for loop** for **multiple Dictionaries**.

Something like this

```
for i in obj1 and obj2 and obj3:

print i.obj1_name
print i.obj2_name
print i.obj3_name
```

Comment: looks like you need `zip`

Comment: the for loop format is incorrect `for i in obj1 and obj2 and obj3:` is not how you write a for loop in python, also what is `i.obj1_name` supposed to mean?

Comment: Dev. i.obj1_name is just an example.

Comment: @TalhaMurtaza do you want the keys that are common to all three dictionaries or all the keys in the dictionaries like in a table format?

Comment: @AlbinPaul both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant but you can loop over a single dictionary which is the merge of the others

```py
for key, value in {**obj1, **obj2, **obj3}:
    pass
```

Comment: will that work for python 2.7 as he mentioned ? I think ZIP will help much better

Comment: That's amazing. Can you elaborate a little please.

Comment: It is a shorthand of combining dictionaries using iterable unpacking. For `a = {1:2}  b = {3:4} c = {5:6}` , `{**a, **b, **c}` gives you `{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}`

Comment: After combining I have to call objects using the respective keys of each item of each **dictionary?**

Answer (score 1):

The best option I think is to use `zip`. The precise usage will depend on whether you want the keys, the values or both, but the loop will more or less remain the same. Example:

```
obj1 = {'test1':'12'}
obj2 = {'test2':'23'}
obj3 = {'test3':'34'}

for a, b, c in zip(obj1, obj2, obj3):
    print a, b, c
```

That will result in: `test1 test2 test3`

Comment: what if we don't use zip?

Comment: Zip is possibly the best option if your only interested for the key of your dictionary and not for their values